# force core location to use gps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geolocation, gps, core-location

I read somewhere in apple documentation that I need to edit the plist to indicate that my app would require a GPS, I can't find this document anymore. I am building a somewhat navigation apps, and I would like to have startUpdatingLocation to use the location from the GPS. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to prevent users with devices that have NO GPS from running your app?  ie: iPod touch does not have GPS but does have CoreLocation using WiFi triangulation.  OR are you trying to get CoreLocation to give you GPS accuracy location updates rather than less accurate WiFi/Cellular triangulation location updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will limit your application to only being able to run on devices with GPS.

[Build-Time Configuration Details](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html)

`gps` is a value of `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` in your plist.

> gps
>
> Include this key if your
>   application requires (or specifically
>   prohibits) the presence of GPS (or
>   AGPS) hardware when tracking
>   locations. (You should include this
>   key only if you need the higher
>   accuracy offered by GPS hardware.) If
>   you include this key, you should also
>   include the location-services key. You
>   should require GPS only if your
>   application needs location data more
>   accurate than the cell or Wi-fi radios
>   might otherwise provide.

Comment: yes... that's what I actually want... otherwise the app will be very useless without a gps

Comment: what if I want to get CoreLocation to give me GPS accuracy all the time?

Comment: I would recommend setting the distanceFilter of your `CLLocationManager` to `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` although this will not guarantee it to always use gps it more than likely will if available. As stated above devices without an actual GPS chip or AGPS usually has access to WiFi positioning which would be something to consider before preventing your application from running on them.

Comment: so basically there is no general way of having the phone to use the GPS all the time to get the location?

Comment: @equinoX - No.  There are occasionally times when other methods are more accurate than GPS (satellites obscured for instance).  Location services will switch automatically, but change the accuracy estimate as well.